# Browser not opening "Index of" directory

Tags: firefox

I’m having problems opening to the root of my browser called “index of” where I can find all my files that are available in the htdocs directory.

I’ve tried typing in the URI but nothing was found. Instead only one file opens up, replacing the “index of” directory that usually shows up in the Mozilla Firefox, each time I click on Apache Admin in the XAMPP control panel.

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is a setting on the server.  You can either set this in .htaccess for the particular directory you want to work with or in apache2.conf to set it globally.

Follow directions here:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/enabling-apache-file-directory-indexing/

Do you have the ability to change these files on the server?

Comment: yes I do have the ability these files on the server